# change log format for dmesg

Tags: logs, dmesg

I am getting my dmesg messages like this,

```
[   27.154743] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (0c45:6a04)
[   27.194956] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

But, I would like `dmesg` log messages to be printed in the format,

```
[DD-MM-HH-mm] SYSTEM_HOSTNAME the-message-content-comes-here
```

On net, I am not seeing any `/etc/dmesg` properties that does this.

Any property that does this?

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner will do, but I think there's more efficient way...

```
dmesg -T | perl -MSys::Hostname -pe 's/^\[(.*?)\]/$_=`date +[%d-%m-%H-%M] -d "$1"`;chomp;$_." ".&hostname/e'
```

Comment: @don_crissti I don't think there's better way than `dmesg -T` to get plausible timestamps from the original dmesg jiffies output, except ones written in `kern.log` using accurate time.